# Wagtail set default page explorer view location for PageChooserBlock in admin

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, wagtail-streamfield, wagtail-admin

Way to browse pages from particular location in PageChooserBlock, like browse "sub pages or same level pages" from current editing page in which this block is used.
I observed that when any page is selected in PageChooserBlock then browsing starts from the same current selected page.
I wanted to start default browsing from current edting page (in which this PageChooserBlock block is used) if no page is already selected.
Is there any way to do it? I googled for some way or direction for doing it but no success.
I also checked [chooser hook](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.2/reference/hooks.html#choosers) but there is no way to get current editing page in this hook. So can't use it.
Also tried to search in source code of PageChooserBlock for such possibility but no success for me or may be I missed the possible way. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done exactly what you seek to do, but I think you may want to subclass [AdminPageChooser](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/v2.11.1/wagtail/admin/widgets/chooser.py#L72) and implement [render_js_init](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/v2.11.1/wagtail/admin/widgets/chooser.py#L115) in order to define a default `parent` of your choosing.

You can then subclass `PageChooserBlock` and implement `widget` in order to return an instance of your subclass of `AdminPageChooser`.

I gave this a quick go and it seemed to work.

Comment: Thank you for replying and sorry for delay from my end. I am trying to implement as your suggestion. The only thing I would like to know is, how I can get **current page id** which is open for edit in  **render_js_init** so that I can set parent page using it?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achive the expected result using suggestion of @rgs258 with some modifications done in JavaScript.
I subclassed **AdminPageChooser** and implemented **media** method and added some sort of hack for getting *pageid* of editing page as below in JavaScript.
I think(know) this is not the perfect way but at least I am able to achive my expected result. Please suggest if there is any better way to do it.

I created new JavaScript file with the below coad and added it in newly implemented **media** method after `page-chooser.js`

```
if(typeof createPageChooser === 'function'){

    let  originalCreatePageChooser = createPageChooser;
    createPageChooser = function(id, pageTypes, openAtParentId, canChooseRoot, userPerms){
        if (!openAtParentId){
            let path = window.location.pathname;
            openAtParentId = path.replace('/admin/pages/', '').replace('/edit/', ''); //Know it is not the best way but ...
        }
        originalCreatePageChooser(id, pageTypes, openAtParentId, canChooseRoot, userPerms);
    }
}
```